# Фильтрация массива объектов

Tags: javascript

Нужно дополнить функцию `getFriends(users)` так, чтобы она возвращала массив друзей всех пользователей (свойство `friends`).

> У нескольких пользователей могут быть одинаковые друзья, сделай так
> чтобы возвращаемый массив не содержал повторений.

Только начала обучение, познаю азы, помогите пожалуйста.

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: "Moore Hensley",
    email: "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    gender: "male",
    age: 37
  },
  {
    name: "Sharlene Bush",
    email: "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Briana Decker", "Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    gender: "female",
    age: 34
  },
  {
    name: "Ross Vazquez",
    email: "rossvazquez@xinware.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Marilyn Mcintosh", "Padilla Garrison", "Naomi Buckner"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    gender: "male",
    age: 24
  },
 
]



// пытаюсь фильтровать, но явно что-то делаю не так...
const getFriends = (users)=> { 
    users.filter(user => user.friends); 
    (el, index, array) => array.indexOf(el) === index;
}
```

Comment: Вам надо перебирать ваш массив и в каждом элементе уже проверять, есть ли друг в списке друзей

Comment: Сделайте так... Возьмите бумажку и записывайте, а как бы вы это делали вручную? Мол берем перевый элемент, смотрим... проверяем... если это то делаем, если нет, то не делаем. Решение придет само )

Comment: если перебирать массив то это все отправлять в цикл, а там если находит уже добавляет в новый массив? Я правильно поняла, просто реально потратила день на задачу и она меня не отпускает )

Comment: Все правильно. В функции создаете массив УНИКАЛЬНЫХ друзей, бежите по циклу, в каждом элементе заходите в еще один цикл и сравниваете, если ли друг в массиву уникальных. Есть, пропускаете, нет, добавляете. По окончанию, возвращаете массив уникальных друзей

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать писать.

Comment: Внизу подсказали, но пытайся сделать сама, а ниже можно подсматривать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внесем еще один вариант, для будущих поколений .

```js
function getFriends(arr) {
  let b =[];  
  
  //Собираем все friends в один array.
  arr.forEach((element)=>{ 
    b = [...b, ...element.friends]; 
  });

  //Производим удаление одинаковых элементов.
  let newArray = b.filter((item, pos) => b.indexOf(item) === pos);
  return newArray;
}

console.log(getFriends(users))
```

Answer (score 2):

Почти в лоб:

```
function getFriends(users) {
  // Результирующий массив
  let a = [];

  // Перебираем пользователей
  for(let user of users) {

    // Перебираем друзей пользователя user
    for( let name of user.friends) {
      // Ищем друга в массиве a
      let index = a.findIndex( v => v === name );

      // Если не нашли, то index === -1
      if (index === -1) {
        // Добавляем нового друга в массив
        a.push(name);
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

Тоже самое, но в одну строку (почти. И вместо `findIndex` попробуем, мм, `includes`):

```
function getFriends(users) {
  let a = [];
  users.forEach( u => u.friends.forEach( f => { if (!a.includes(f)) a.push(f); }) );
  return a;
}
```

Через Set

```
function getFriends(users) {
  let s = new Set();
  for(let u of users) {
    // Пытаемся всех друзей очередного пользователя добавить в набор
    // повторяющиеся будут проигнорированы
    s = new Set([...s, ...u.friends]);
  }
  // Преобразуем набор в массив
  return Array.from(s);
}

console.log(getFriends(users));
```

Answer (score 2):

Методом .reduce()

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: "Moore Hensley",
    email: "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    gender: "male",
    age: 37
  },
  {
    name: "Sharlene Bush",
    email: "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Briana Decker", "Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    gender: "female",
    age: 34
  },
  {
    name: "Ross Vazquez",
    email: "rossvazquez@xinware.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Marilyn Mcintosh", "Padilla Garrison", "Naomi Buckner"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    gender: "male",
    age: 24
  },

]

function getFriends(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    item.friends.forEach(friend => {
      if (!acc.includes(friend)) acc.push(friend);
    })
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(getFriends(users))
```

Answer (score 2):

ну раз пошла такая пьянка )

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: "Moore Hensley",
    email: "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    gender: "male",
    age: 37
  },
  {
    name: "Sharlene Bush",
    email: "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Briana Decker", "Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    gender: "female",
    age: 34
  },
  {
    name: "Ross Vazquez",
    email: "rossvazquez@xinware.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Marilyn Mcintosh", "Padilla Garrison", "Naomi Buckner"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    gender: "male",
    age: 24
  },
 
]

function getFriends(users) {
  return [...new Set(users.map(user => user.friends).flat())]
}
console.log(getFriends(users))
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

```
const getFriends = users.flatMap(user => user.friends).filter((friend, index, array) => array.indexOf(friend) === index);
```

Можно разбить на 2 части:

```
const allFriends = users.flatMap(user => user.friends);
const getFriends = allFriends.filter((friend, index, array) => array.indexOf(friend) === index);
console.log(getFriends);
```